# How to calculate the following Gaussian integral?

Tags: calculus

Here I have an integral which I supposed to calculate using Gaussian integral:

$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2 \eta e^{-(\lambda |{\eta|}^2-\mu \lambda+\nu \eta ^\star)}
$$

And I also know the answer which is:

$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{\frac{\mu \nu}{\lambda}}
$$

Question:
I really don't know how to calculate this. If it is real integral and one dimensional then it is somehow easy for me. but know I have no idea about this. How should I treat the complex terms and two dimension?

Comment: By the way $\lambda$ is real positive. $\nu$ and $\mu$ is arbitrary complex numbers.

Comment: Is it $d^2\eta$ or $d\eta$?

Comment: it is $d^2\eta$, so I am confusing.

Comment: Just as a first guess, taking $\eta = x+ iy$ and  $d^2\eta = dx dy$?

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea.  If $\eta=x+iy$, then how can we get $d^2\eta=dxdy$  ?

Comment: I we assume $\eta$ is real, can you solve this problem?

Comment: If we assume that $\eta$ is real, $d^2\eta$ doesn't make any sense since $\eta$ changes over real line (1 dimension). But I guess this integral is over complex plane (2-dimensions).

Comment: There's a $e^{\mu \lambda}$ in the integral which should come out (doesn't depend on $\eta$) and I think should appear in the final answer somehow. Is the final answer right?

Comment: Yes, the final answer is right. I'm sure with 100%.

Comment: I really hope you can help me to solve this.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $η=x+iy$, and $d^2η=dxdy$,

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int d^2 \eta e^{-(\lambda |{\eta|}^2-\mu \lambda+\nu \eta ^\star)} &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-(\lambda {x}^2-\mu \lambda+\nu x)} \mathrm{d}x \times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(\lambda {y}^2-i \nu y)} \mathrm{d}y \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}} e^{\frac{\nu^2}{4 \lambda}} \times \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}} e^{\frac{-\nu^2}{4 \lambda}} \times e^{\lambda \mu} \\
&=& \frac{\pi}{\lambda} e^{\lambda \mu}
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

so:

$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2 \eta e^{-(\lambda |{\eta|}^2-\mu \lambda+\nu \eta ^\star)} = \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{\lambda \mu}
$$

Similar to your answer but not quite the same!